# How to convert datetime64 [ns, UTC] into time stamp?

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to convert the datetime in my dataset which is in `datetime64 [ns, UTC]`  eg. `2022-02-27 23:51:55+00:00` format into timestamp which i can use to pass as input argument for my Neural Network model. Currently what i have works but it does not work very well. Are there any built in functions that I can use? Thank you

Code:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

df['measurementTimeDefault'] = pd.to_datetime(df.measurementTimeDefault).dt.tz_localize(None)

dateTime64 = pd.to_datetime(df.measurementTimeDefault)

df['measurementTimeDefault'] = (dateTime64 - np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')) / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
```

Comment: `datetime64` is a timestamp, so I'm not sure what you are looking for. What do you mean "it does not work very well"? What format do you need for your neural network? What problems have you encountered?

Comment: I'm looking to convert it into a float value

Comment: Is an integer value good enough? I think epoch time is usually an int, not a float.

Answer (score -1):

Converting to epoch should do the trick.
I.E.

```py
def convert_to_epoch(timestamp):
    timestamp = timestamp.split('.')[0]
    dt_object = datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return dt_object
```